# Opening domain computer's explorer from elevated PS script still prompts for credentials

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

I have a PowerShell script which requires admin rights to launch and therefore always runs elevated. It has options to run commands on remote computers on the same domain, which all work without re-prompting for credentials as the shell is already elevated. However, when trying to open the file explorer from a machine on the domain, no matter which method I use, access is denied and I am re-prompted for admin creds. This includes using `ii` or `Invoke-Item`, and `explorer.exe` with and without `Start-Process` and/or `-verb runas`. Here's a sample command as I am trying to run it:

`Invoke-Item \\$systemName\C$\TEMP`

To be clear, that command itself works with all the methods mentioned above, I'm simply trying to avoid the second credential request, which I don't understand since every other admin command runs without re-prompting. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a Windows policy as: [Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-do-not-allow-storage-of-passwords-and-credentials-for-network-authentication)